# How to align a Material UI Button and TextField on the same line, at same height?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get a `<Button>` from the Material UI library to a) sit at same height as the `<TextField>` next to it; and b) have it be aligned with that same field.

Both the `<Button>` and the `<TextField>` are each inside their own `<Grid>` component (with a container wrapping them).

The container `<Grid>` has the prop `alignItems="center"`, which produces this result:
[image]

It's here I'm running into difficult trying to get the height of the `<Button>` to match that of the input field. This must be a relatively common requirement - is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you have each of your element in a `<Grid>` component themselves, this should work:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-forked-1yymw?file=/app.jsx

Comment: Not quite - that's the same as what I have in my screenshot. I need to make the button the same height as the text field so they're all equally aligned.

Comment: ah sorry, I completely missed your point. So you need `align-items: stretch` to let the element occupies the entire available space. See the link again, I updated it

Comment: No worries - thanks for helping! I still can't seem to produce the effect; I think it's because I'm using a `Paper` component. Would you mind taking a look at what I have here: https://7271d.csb.app/

Comment: Ah just remove `margin="normal"` from your `<TextField>`s (or set it to "none"), as it's making the Grid item taller and thus the button is stretching too much "following" the Grid margin

Comment: You're a legend mate. Such a simple fix. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3):

Use `container={true}` for `Grid` to set it as a flex container. Aside from that, you can always leverage `makeStyles` to generally customize the components' style

MUI [Grid container prop](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#props)

> If true, the component will have the flex container behavior.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  fullHeightButton: {
    height: "100%"
  }
});

function App() {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container={true}>
        <TextField variant="outlined"/>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">+</Button>
      </Grid>
      
      <br/>
      
      <Grid container={true}>
        <Grid><TextField variant="outlined"/></Grid>
        <Grid><Button classes={{root: classes.fullHeightButton}} variant="contained" color="primary">+</Button></Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("test"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel">
    const { Button, Grid, makeStyles, TextField } = MaterialUI;
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: How would you achieve this same result with both the `Button` and `TextField` inside their own respective `Grid` components, but both still wrapped in the container? This is the issue I'm dealing with

Comment: I'd just resort to `makeStyles`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had two buttons that sandwiched a `TextField`, where the spacing between the first button and the textfield was wrong as shown:

[Buttons before code addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9LFa.jpg)

My code was:

```
  <CardActions className='cardactions'>
    <Button variant='contained' color='error'> - </Button>
    <TextField id='outlined-basic' variant='outlined' size='small' type='number' label='Enter Quantity'/>
    <Button variant='contained' color='success'>+</Button>
  </CardActions>
```

Adding  `sx={{ marginRight:1}}` to the first button corrected the issue.

[Buttons after code addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8S3b.jpg)

Code after addition:

```
  <CardActions className='cardactions'>
    <Button variant='contained' color='error' sx={{ marginRight:1}}> - </Button>
    <TextField id='outlined-basic' variant='outlined' size='small' type='number' label='Enter Quantity'/>
    <Button variant='contained' color='success'>+</Button>
  </CardActions>
```